# How to have curl destroy/reset connection?

Tags: http, curl

I am trying to recreate an intermittent issue I see with our test automation and am using `curl` (not `libcurl`) in a loop. But I see in the headers `Connection #0 to host storage.googleapis.com left intact` in successive requests in my loop. I want the connection to be destroyed/reset every time. The issue I am trying to test is on the TLS handshake and re-using the connection won't help.

I searched `man curl` for 'destroy' and 'reset' with no results and all the results for my web searches are around others getting connection resets, so it is a bit noisy.

I feel like this might be at the OS level.

How do I have `curl` reset the connection immediately?

Comment: Why don't you try closing the handle after each loop `curl_close($ch);`

Comment: Sourcode will be helpful

Comment: sorry, to clarify, this is the CLI curl, not libcurl. Just updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl doesn't have such an option (while libcurl does) but you can often achieve the same effect by insisting on doing the request using HTTP/1.0 with the `--http1.0` option.

This has this effect because in HTTP/1.0 persistent connections were not the default.

Comment: Thank you! `--http1.0` is working nicely for this test now! You also prompted me to thing about using `openssl` for the test as well, as this test is just testing the handshake.